# Extract elements from a vector of object

Tags: c++, vector

Given a vector of objects, is there an elegant way to extract its member? I am currently just using a for loop but it would be nice if there is a way to do it. Example:

```
#include <vector>

struct Object {
  int x;
  float y;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<Object> obj;
  // Fill up obj

  std::vector<int> all_x = obj.x; // Won't work obviously
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `std::vector` (or c++ in general) does not support covariant aggregation, there is no syntactically pretty way to do what you want.

If you really want to **initialize** `all_x` with `x` members of `obj` elements, then you can define a new iterator class, like that:

```
class getx_iter : public vector<Object>::iterator
{
public:
    getx_iter(const vector<Object>::iterator &iter) : vector<Object>::iterator(iter) {}
    int operator*() { return (*this)->x; }
};
```

[Working code example](http://ideone.com/8Q4hTm)

If you're okay with initializing an empty `vector` and then filling it, `std::transform` with a labmda is a clearer option (as @andars suggested).

You could also avoid extra initialization by using `vector::reserve()` and `back_inserter`:

```
xs.reserve(foos.size());
std::transform(foos.begin(), foos.end(), back_inserter(xs), [](Foo f){return f.x;});
```

Also notice that while `x` is a private member of `Object` and has no getters, it will be quite hard to extract it.

Answer (score 6):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), it would simply be

```
std::vector<int> xs = objs | ranges::view::transform(&Object::x);
```

or just use the view:

```
auto xs = objs | ranges::view::transform(&Object::x);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d20f45854cf1bdbe)

Comment: And now it's standardized https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WPzP8qexa

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a really good way.

One alternative would be to use `std::transform` with a lambda.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int x_): x(x_) {}
    int x;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> foos;
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        foos.push_back(Foo(i));
    }

    std::vector<int> xs;
    xs.resize(foos.size());
    std::transform(foos.begin(), foos.end(), xs.begin(), [](Foo f){return f.x;});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some template and macro magic, and it works:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int x_): x(x_) {}
    int x;
};

#define GETFIELD(type, field) [](const type & obj){return obj.field;}

template<typename T,typename U, typename TMapper>
void MapVector(vector<T>& src, vector<U>& dst, TMapper mapper) {
    for (const auto& it: src) {
        dst.push_back(mapper(it));
    }
}

#define MapVectorField(src, dst, field) MapVector(src, dst, GETFIELD(decltype(src)::value_type, field))

int main() {
    vector<Foo> vFoo;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        vFoo.push_back(Foo(i));
    }

    vector<int> vX;
    MapVector(vFoo, vX, GETFIELD(Foo, x));
    MapVectorField(vFoo, vX, x);

    for (int i = 0; i < vX.size(); i++) {
        printf("%d\n", vX[i]);
    }
}
```

Of course, remember that it is not very good to name macro `MapVectorField` as it is function, or write `using namespace std` in production.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another macro that's pretty easy to use.  It does require the programmer to know that the internal loop variable name is "e", for element.  If you keep that in mind, it will work for both fields or methods, and also for normal objects or pointers to objects.

The macro is simply:

```
#define map(vTarget, vSource, eField) \
            for (auto e: vSource) { vTarget.push_back(eField); }
```

For example, suppose we have a class named Person which has a string name field and an int age field, and we want to extract just the names into a new vector.  An example usage might then be:

```
map(names, people, e.name);
```

Note the "e" in the third parameter.  This is required because the macro uses the variable "e" to iterator over the elements in the vector.  So keep in mind which syntax you need to use.  I believe these are the 4 cases:

- e.field
- e.method()
- e->field
- e->method()

Let's try them out.  Here's a full example.  Hey, if anyone has a more elegant join solution, I'm all ears.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


#define map(vTarget, vSource, eField) \
            for (auto e: vSource) { vTarget.push_back(eField); } 



class Person {
    public:
        string name;
        int    age;

    public:
        Person(string name, int age) {
            this->name=name;
            this->age=age;
        }
        string& getName() {return name;}
        int     getAge()  {return age;}
};


string join(vector<string> vSource, const string separator) {
    string buf;
    bool first=true;

    for (string e: vSource) {
        if (first) {
            first=false;
        } else {
            buf+=separator;
        }
        buf+=e;
    }
    return buf;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

// using a normal Object
    vector<Person> people;
    vector<string> names; 

    people.push_back(Person("john", 27));
    people.push_back(Person("jane", 26));


    names.clear();
    map(names, people, e.name);
    cout << join(names, ",") << endl;    

    names.clear();
    map(names, people, e.getName());
    cout << join(names, ",") << endl;    


// using a pointer to an object
    vector<Person*>  morePeople;
    morePeople.push_back(new Person("bob", 27));
    morePeople.push_back(new Person("amy", 26));

    names.clear();
    map(names, morePeople, e->name);
    cout << join(names, ",") << endl;    

    names.clear();
    map(names, morePeople, e->getName());
    cout << join(names, ",") << endl;    

}
```

Sample output:

```
john,jane
john,jane
bob,amy
bob,amy
```